# How to create the same random number twice for dialogflow

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es

I am trying to create a chatbot using Dialogflow and a flask webhook to teach mathematics, one of the features of it is to give and answer questions. I had made it so that the chatbot would create random numbers, then ask a question. The user then answers, then the chatbot checks the answer. The problem is, every time the user states a message in the chat window, it sends a new request to the webhook. Creating new random numbers in the process. Because of this I would like to know if there is anyway to generate the same random number twice, or somehow save these values in dialogflow or externally from the webhook.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the seed in `random` module. Every time you set the seed to a specific number, the random sequence is started to generate from the specific number. For example:

```
import random

print(random.random(), random.random()) # 0.473694231423486 0.9982145771110763
print(random.random(), random.random()) # 0.48084261447054455 0.7666080217170774
random.seed(12345)
print(random.random(), random.random()) # 0.41661987254534116 0.010169169457068361
random.seed(12345)
print(random.random(), random.random()) # 0.41661987254534116 0.010169169457068361
```

Note that the last two sequences are random, but equal.